# Can ms dos list all files and directory (including hidden ones)

Tags: ms-dos

I think there used to be a command called

```
dir -a
```

or something like that.

Now it's no longer there isn't it?

To see hidden file we need

```
dir /a:h
```

which will show only hidden files, which is not what I want.

So how to display **all** files, whether hidden or not?

Comment: `dir /?` will help you here...

Comment: I did. No such option to search all.

Comment: You didn't read to well then. You can use `/s` to recursively look in directories to find all files, and `/a` on its own to not care about attributes.

Comment: @PhonicUK: I respectfully disagree, there is no mention of the behaviour of `/a` alone in the help I get with `/?`. I read it a couple of times to be sure.

Comment: Okay which one is correct here? Anyone tested this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list all attributes in `/a`. That'd be `dir /a:drhsa` on real DOS and a few more letters on Windows with NTFS, all listed under `/a` in help.

Comment: What few letters?  Why not listed some of the uses?  How about fully explain what `dir /a:drhas` actually does?

Comment: @Ramhound, show me "Windows" in question and I think about explicitly mentioning them. "d, r, h, s, a", if it is not plainly obvious to somebody, are "all attributes", mentioned in previous sentence. Also, what *additional* uses except requested, quoting: **all** files, you propose to me to list?

Answer (score 13):

`dir /a` lists everything, visible and hidden files altogether.

Comment: Does it still work? I don't see that in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my comment above, it's not in the `/?` anymore. However I tried it before posting.

Comment: I think this should be selected based on large number of votes. I still do not know why this answer is better than the rest. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @JimThio, this is the correct answer, and the answer provided by Oleg is wrong. `dir` lists only files and directories that have every attribute in the `/a:` set. So use the empty set, i.e. just `/a`.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the environment, dir /a may work.

In other systems, dir /A: may be needed.  That is, put a colon after the /A

This answer might apply to JP Software's 4DOS, as well.

Another option is to not use DIR, but to use the ATTRIB command.  You're probably familiar with that command for changing file attributes.  However, it can also be useful for simply showing files.

Answer (score 0):

The undocumented "**dir,**" (dir followed by a comma, no space) will show all files, including both hidden and system files. Not deleted files thou, use **undelete** to show those.